# Elixir, unpacking argument from list or tuple

Tags: arguments, parameter-passing, elixir, metaprogramming

I would like to get the following to run

```
def myfunction(a, b) do
    IO.puts "Success"
end

def runstuff do
    jobs = {&myfunction/2, [1, 3]}
    {to_run, args} = jobs
    to_run.(args) # broken code
end
```

Well, the code above is broken but I think shows what I would like to achieve, I'm a happy Elixir newbie (apparently :)) I'm hoping that it can be solved with some elixir macro magic.
Edit: moved in jobs according to comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you might want to take a look is [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3).

This is pattern known as `MFA`: `Module`, `Function`, `Arguments`. This requires your functions to be defined in some module.

Please consider following example:

```
defmodule Fun do
  def myfunction(a, b) do
    IO.puts "Success, a: #{a}, b: #{b}"
  end

  def runstuff do
    jobs = {Fun, :myfunction, [1, 3]}
    {m, f, a} = jobs
    apply(m, f, a)
  end
end

Fun.runstuff
```

So:

```
▶ elixir fun.exs
Success, a: 1, b: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your real example involves a much longer list of args, but this is how to get your example to work.

```
def myfunction(a, b) do
    IO.puts "Success"
end

def runstuff do
    jobs = {&myfunction/2, [1, 3]}
    {to_run, [a, b]} = jobs
    to_run.(a,b) # unbroken code
end
```

Comment: You are right with your assumption. I do have long list with different functions all potentially taking different amount of arguments. And that's where your solution doesn't fit. Thanks anyway!